# Google analytics: How to access Analytics API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api, analytics, google-api-java-client

I have Google Analytics account already. I also have reports generated. I need to access those reports programmatically in Java. What API do I need to use to access it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you have a specific question? you use the Analytics API.

Comment: your not going to be able to access those reports exactly your going to have to build them again using the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). The 
[Hello Analytics API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java) and
[Working with the API developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) have examples that show how to access the API in Java.